# Find partial derivatives of function f(x,y) where f(x,y) is defined as an integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

<. Find the partial derivatives *<(x,y)*< and *<(x,y)*<, in terms of the function <, where the function < is defined by the following integral.

<$$
f(x,y)=\int_a^bh(t) dt
$$

$<$
a=ysin(x^3)
$$
and
$$ 
b=x^3cos(y^2)
$$

Comment: The limits of integration are variable, so the entire expression is a function of $x$ and $y$. Thus it makes sense to find the indicated partials.

Comment: Think of this as $f(x,y)=\int_{a(x,y)}^{b(x,y)}h(t)dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
For simplicity, assume there is an anti-derivative $H(t)$ for $h(t)$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
f(x,y) = \int_{y \sin (x^3)}^{x^3 \cos(y^2)} h(t) dt
       = H\left(x^3 \cos\left(y^2\right)\right) - H\left(y \sin \left(x^3\right)\right)
$$
and now, use the chain rule:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 = H'\left(x^3 \cos\left(y^2\right)\right)
   \frac{\partial x^3 \cos\left(y^2\right)}{\partial x}
   - H'\left(y \sin \left(x^3\right)\right)
     \frac{\partial y \sin \left(x^3\right)}{\partial x}
$$
and now use $H'=h$ and do the arithmetic...

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y) = \int_{y\sin(x^3)}^{x^3\cos(y^2)} h(t) dt = \int_{0}^{x^3\cos(y^2)} h(t) dt - \int_{0}^{y\sin(x^3)} h(t) dt$$

Now use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$f_x(x,y) = h(x^3 \cos(y^2))(3x^2\cos(y^2)) - h(y\sin(x^3))(y\cos(x^3)\cdot3x^2)$$
$$f_y(x,y) = h(x^3 \cos(y^2))(-x^3\sin(y^2)\cdot 2y) - h(y\sin(x^3))(\sin(x^3))$$